# Unable to access env variables from dockerfile in React app using webpack DefinePlugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, npm, webpack

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. console.log prints `undefined`. `Makefile`, `config.env`, `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` are all in root of the project.

Makefile:

```
docker-run: docker
    docker run -it --env-file config.env -p "80:80" app
```

config.env

```
API_KEY=https://test.com
```

webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            BASE_URL: JSON.stringify('https://myapp.firebaseio.com'),
            'process.env.API_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_KEY)
        })
    ]
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(process.env.API_KEY);//undefined
        console.log(process.env.BASE_URL);//undefined
        console.log(BASE_URL);//undefined
    }, []);
    return (
        <></>
    );
};
```

Package.json(`npm run docker`)

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "rm -rf dist && webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot --port 8090",
        "docker": "rm -rf dist && webpack --mode production && make docker-run"
    },
```

Comment: exec into the container and printenv, what is the output?

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I can see here is,  you are building the project outside of docker and pushing the artifacts (after build) to docker for serving the webapp.

As per the documentation of `DefinePlugin` 
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

> The DefinePlugin allows you to create global constants which can be
>   configured at compile time

Which means, If you have a `App.js` component like below

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <p>[process.env.test] = {process.env.test}</p>
        <p>[process.env.NODE_ENV] = {process.env.NODE_ENV}</p>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And webpack config

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({"process.env.test": JSON.stringify(process.env.test)})
```

After running `NODE_ENV=production test="A test variable" npm run build` (Which internally runs `webpack --mode production` if bootstrapped with create-react-app)

The component gets compiled to (Only relevant parts of webpack compiled code pasted).

```
 var i = function() {
        return a.a.createElement(
          "div",
          null,
          a.a.createElement(
            "p",
            null,
            "[process.env.test] = ",
            "A test variable"
          ),
          a.a.createElement(
            "p",
            null,
            "[process.env.NODE_ENV] = ",
            "production"
          )
        );
      }
```

Here it replaced `{process.env.test}` and `{process.env.NODE_ENV}` to `A test variable` and `production` **at compile time**.

**Setting any environment variables  on server after the build has no effect on the compiled file**.

**And due to the direct injection of env variables in compiled code, you shouldn't use this to store confidential information  (secrets/ private tokens, passwords, IP addresses of internal servers etc).**

So, the solution to your original problem might be, to build the artifacts inside the docker container. A sample Docker file follows.

```
FROM node:10 as react-app
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Set a temporary variable
ENV test="Hello Docker"
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.12-alpine
COPY --from=react-app /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

A sample git repo if you need a reference.

https://github.com/nithinthampi/test-defineplugin.